# Generic inheritance in Java, multiple type parameter

Tags: java, generics

In my task I need to extend T with class and use S which is implementation of another class.

First part I did like this:

```
public class Animal<T extends Colour>
```

I tried with & between <> but I know that only 1 class can be extended. My question is how to implement S so that it could be implemented.

> ```
> public class Animal<T extends Colour & S implement anotherClass>
> ```

This line of code doesn't work.

I can do 3 things:

1. T can inherit Colour or and implement otherClass
2. T can be instance of Colour and inherit otherClass
3. T extend Colour and S extend otherClass <--- I did this

Comment: Are you saying `T` _also_ has to implement `S`, or that `S` is separate and must implement `AnotherClass`?

Comment: If you want two type parameters, you should use `public class Animal<T extends Colour, S extends anotherClass>`. If `T` must be an instance of both, then it's `Animal<T extends Colour & AnotherInterface` where the second can only be an interface.

Comment: But this can very well be an XY problem. Please explain the problem you're trying to solve if you want meaningful answers.